# return student information - SQL/C# assignment

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2012

so essentially, I have two text fields, one with the firstName and one with the lastName of the student. What I want the program to do is this:

return the student's phone number and comments using the firstName and lastName from the `TextBox` above. This is what I have so far:

```
if (actionButton.Text == "Update")
{
    SqlConnection cn;
    cn = new SqlConnection();
    cn.ConnectionString = "Data source=(local); Initial Catalog=INT422Assignment1; Integrated Security=SSPI;";
    cn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd;
    cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = cn;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, Comments FROM myTable WHERE firstName LIKE @firstName AND lastName LIKE @lastName"; //AND lastName LIKE @lastName"
    //used this part to delete records

    SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@firstName";
    param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
    param.Value = firstNameTB.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

    param.ParameterName = "@lastName";
    param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
    param.Value = lastNameTB.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

    //display data in a listbox
    SqlDataReader reader;
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        string s;
        s = reader["firstName"].ToString() + "-" + reader["lastName"].ToString() + reader["phoneNumber"].ToString() + reader["Comments"].ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(s);
    }

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cn.Close();
}
```

I'm not sure where to go from here. In the code I have placed two comment statements, so I have used the above in two different parts of my assignment, but when I bring them together, it doesn't work.

what is happening is that I am not getting any results. Essentially I need it to give me the phone number and comments of the student indicated in the two text boxes

Comment: What problem you facing? Any error, exception..??

Comment: "it doesn't work" is a poor description of the problem. Explain what **does** happen, what you expect to happen and describe and exceptions/error that come up.

Comment: sorry, please see above. I made an edit to my question.

Comment: Check your query by executing it and replacing the values for the parameters with the passed in values in SSMS - I suspect that your SQL is incorrect (depends on the types of the fields for first and last name).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're getting an error, yes? You are trying to do two operations on the same command object and my hazy recollection says that's not going to work. Try removing this line.

```
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

If you have studied the using statement, that's typically a better solution for handling resources like your connection and reader.

Comment: I was about to ask the same thing: what's the non-query he's trying to execute? Also, don't forget to close your reader before closing the connection.

Comment: **EVERYONE THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP AND INPUT**

I removed the following: 
    
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

and changed my code to use param1 and param2. I would post it but I have to wait 8 hours cause I have less than 10 reputation. I will post t in 8 hours.. LOL!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (actionButton.Text == "Update")
{
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
    cn.ConnectionString = "Data source=(local); Initial Catalog=INT422Assignment1; Integrated Security=SSPI;";
    cn.Open();

    MessageBox.Show(cn.ConnectionState.ToString());
// If you are shown "Open" by above messagebox and you are using correct table and column names then you will get accurate results by following code

    SqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, Comments FROM myTable WHERE firstName LIKE '" + firstNameTB.Text + "' AND lastName LIKE  '" + lastNameTB.Text + "' "; 
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    string s = "";
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        s = reader["firstName"].ToString() + "-" + reader["lastName"].ToString() + reader["phoneNumber"].ToString() + reader["Comments"].ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(s);
    }    
    cn.Close();
}
```